# How do I tint my monitor red for nighttime use?

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

I like my monitor dim and red-tinted at night.  I used to use

```
xcalib -green .1 0 1 -alter
xcalib -blue  .1 0 1 -alter
```

on my laptop.  I'm now using a raspberry pi2 with an HP 2010i monitor and `xcalib` is completely ignored.  Likewise `xgamma`.

Answer (score 2):

Does `xcalib` or `xgamma` work on your pi with another monitor? Likewise, if you have another Linux box, do both utilities work for your monitor?

Another idea: have you tried using redshift? From the [website](http://jonls.dk/redshift/):

> Redshift adjusts the color temperature of your screen according to
>   your surroundings. This may help your eyes hurt less if you are
>   working in front of the screen at night. This program is inspired by
>   f.lux (please see this post for the reason why I started this
>   project).

Comment: This is a decent suggestion, but I think the fact that redshift says "Your graphics driver and X server needs to either support at least RANDR version 1.3 or the VidMode extension" will mean this one is not viable either.  I'd guess they (redshift, xcalib, etc.) all make use of the same underlying mechanism (there would only be so many ways to do this, possibly only one, without at least hacking the driver) and the generic X driver used on the pi (fbdev) is pretty basic.

Comment: Redshift didn't work either and I've only got one monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Also **[f.lux](https://justgetflux.com)** can be your answer.